# PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED not received

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-webhooks

I've implemented `PayPal` recurring payments following [this guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/).

All seems to be working, the subscription is created when the sandbox customer purchase it, but the problem's that I reiceve on the webhook only this event: `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CREATED`, I should receive also: `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED` but I haven't

I also logged in to the sandbox customer account and I don't see any transaction, seems that the subscription is only created but not paid for. What could cause this? The sandbox customer has available balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could cause this?

It is normal. You need to wait for the first payment in the billing cycle to actually occur.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't get your point. Suppose I buy a subscription today using the PayPal smart button, at the end of the checkout the system ask for a confirmation about the agreement. The user accept the agreement and the subscription is created. I reiceve `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CREATED`. Now I expect to receive the money, in fact the user immediately have access to the service for which he paid, why should I wait for the renewal of the subscription to get the money? The list of the transactions is always empty for that customer, almost as if no subscription has been purchased

Comment: The first payment of the first cycle is not created at checkout time.

Comment: And when is it created? Where can I read more about this mechanism? I can't find anything about the documentation.
I am quite perplexed, if the user activates the subscription, he accesses my service and subsequently cancels it, I will not receive the money anyway.
I need to test the flow of webhooks for my system.

Comment: The date of the first billing will be according to what you specified in the plan creation.  You can get or view the details of the profile (subscription ID/ I-####) that the payer approved if you need to double check the date of the first billing. The payment will occur on that date.

Comment: I've created a `Monthly Plan`, which have the following details: https://pastebin.com/5DtRixju what can I do to receive payment immediately upon activation of the subscription?

Comment: If charging on the date the profile is created is not soon enough for you, you could make a plan with a setup_fee of 14.99 and a trial of total_cycles:1, and then have your existing 14.99 monthly after that.

Comment: Could you please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61523787/how-to-activate-a-paypal-subscription ?