# How to activate a PayPal subscription?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I've implemented a recurring payments system using `PayPal` and the `SmartButtons`. The customer is able to create the subscription through my system, at the end of the checkout I get the subscription created:

```
{
    "orderID": "3JR7411152833961C",
    "subscriptionID": "I-J8CHJ9UKB8JU",
    "facilitatorAccessToken": "A21AAElq71jrRrKHzaxxOeA4o7cOie83F_N-LKMZoAe2mhmaANy-a784yj9DUbSlQPIxtu_O-7XyzHWab23gKVgwhqK9Hjaow"
}
```

in order to activate the subscription and get the payment I need to execute it, so I wrote this method:

```
let executeAgreement = (paymentToken) => {

    paypal.billingAgreement.execute(paymentToken, {}, function (error, billingAgreement) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            throw error;
        }
        else {
            console.log('Billing Agreement Execute Response');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(billingAgreement));
        }
    });
}
```

the problem's that I got:

> response: {
>       name: 'BUSINESS_VALIDATION_ERROR',
>       debug_id: '82426af46aee4',
>       message: 'Validation Error.',
>       information_link: 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements#errors',
>       details: [ [Object] ],
>       httpStatusCode: 400
>     },
>     httpStatusCode: 400
>   }

I send to `executeAgreement` the subscriptionId, but I guess the problem it's just that, in the created subscription I only reiceve the id of the subscription not the `paymentToken`, how can I fix?

Essentially: how can I execute/activate the subscription if I've only the subscription id returned by the following method:

```
 opts.createSubscription = function (data, actions) {
     that.step = that.steps.PAYPAL_EXTERNAL_WINDOW;
          return actions.subscription.create({
              plan_id: that.paymentData.plan.id,
              application_context: {
              user_action: "CONTINUE",
              shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
          }
     });
}
```

the method above return `orderId - subscriptionId - facilitatorAccessToken`, seems I'm not able to activate the subscription id after the user as approved the recurring payment through the smart payment buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `I-J8CHJ9UKB8JU` is already a created and active subscription and you don't need to execute anything.

The notion of executing a billing agreement is something from old documentation that predates the Subscriptions API.

In the current Sbscriptions API, you would simply create and activate a subscription:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create

Followed by either a redirection to an approval URL, or use of the Smart Payment Button (which is much better, since it opens up an "in context" approval -- no need for any redirect)

So anyway, you have your active Subscription ID: `I-J8CHJ9UKB8JU`

Now just save this object and associate it with your customer object.

Comment: Using `billing/subscriptions` I can see the subscription details, and I noticed that the subscription is not activated but have as status `APPROVED`, I've pasted the full response here: https://pastebin.com/g5QLsyrD 
maybe there is something wrong in the plan subscribed? My goal is get immediately the payment after the user has subscribed to it, plan details: https://pastebin.com/i7MvGizt

Comment: Well you have `user_action: "CONTINUE",`, that probably makes for an extra review step and needing to send an explicit activate API call

Comment: Okay, so removing `user_action` the subscription shuold be activated automatically, but suppose that I need this extra validation step, how can I validate the subscription and activate it through the node js SDK API?

Comment: The SDKs do not support the new Subscriptiosn API, so you will need to implement the equivalent the HTTPS curl post in the API reference https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_activate